# How to monitoring an MM2 process

Tags: apache-kafka

From KIP-382, There is a metric to find the count of records replicated. But not a direct way of calculating lag. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0#KIP382:MirrorMaker2.0-PublicInterfaces

i start a mm2 process in a node and start kafka with jmx_port, but when i used jconsole to find mm2 monitor mbean , i cant find kafka.mirror.connect ?

JMX_PORT=9988 ./bin/kafka_server_start -daemon config/server.properties   # start kafka

./bin/connect-mirror-maker.sh conf/mm2.properties   # start mm2